# AWK Matching Positive and Negative Numbers

Tags: regex, unix, awk

I have a data that looks like this:

```
-1033  
-  
222
100
-30
-
10
```

What I want to do is to capture all the numbers excluding "dash only" entry.

Why my awk below failed?

```
 awk '$4 != "-" {print $4}'
```

Comment: Works for me, with GNU awk. Are you sure you're referring to the right field? ($4)

Comment: thought the same. looks suspicious

Comment: i think awk '!/-/' could work too. i read it is the same as awk '!($0 ~ "-")' but i'm not totally sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `awk` script says

> If the fourth field is not a dash, print it out

However, you want to print it out if the line is not a dash

```
awk '$0 != "-"'
```

Default action is to print so no body is needed.

If you want to print group of numbers, you can use a GNU awk extension if you use gawk. It allows splitting records using regular expressions:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { RS="(^|\n)-($|\n)" } { print "Numbers:\n" $0 }'
```

Now, instead of lines, it takes a group of numbers separated by a line containing only `-`. Setting the field separator (`FS`) to a newline allows you to iterate over the numbers within such a group:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { FS="\n"; RS="(^|\n)-($|\n)" } 
      { print "Numbers:"; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print " *: " $i }'
```

However I agree with other answers. If you just want to filter out lines matching some text, `grep` is the better tool for that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your data file *is* actually multi-column, and that the values are in column 4, the following will work:

```
awk '$4 != "-" {print $4} {}'
```

It prints the value only where it isn't "-". Your version will probably print the value regardless (or twice) since the default action is to print. Adding the `{}` makes the default action "do nothing".

If the data is actually as shown (one column only), you should be using `$1` rather than `$4` - I wouldn't use `$0` since that's the whole line and it appears you have spaces at the end of your first two lines which would cause `$0` to be `"-1033  "` and `"-  "`.

But, if it were a single column, I wouldn't use awk at all but rather:

```
grep -v '^-$'
grep -v '^ *- *$'
```

the second allowing for spaces on either side of the `"-"` character.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you checking `$4`?  It appears you should check `$1` or `$0` as litb said.

But awk is a heavyweight tool for this job.  Try

```
grep -v '^-$'
```

To remove lines containing only a dash or

```
grep -v '^ *- *$'
```

To remove lines containing only a dash and possibly some space characters.

Comment: The file may actually be a multi-column file with the relevant values in column 4. That was my reading. For example, a share transaction file containing date, stock, dollar-value and quantity on each line, and you're only interested in real quantities. (cont...)

Comment: ... Things like return of capital would involve changes in purchase price but not quantity.

Comment: Could be, but in that case why does it fail?  Beats me.